# Spring boot migration-sslbundle-how to set sslbundle properties wuth external cloud:// paths

Tags: spring

I am currently working on spring boot migration from spring boot 2.7 to 3.1.4.One of my project is having jks files and logic in configuration class to load the jks,trust create sslcontext by passing Httpclient and ssl connectivity.But as due to spring boot upgrade httpclient4 is also updated to Httpclient5
so old classic ssl code is breaking.Tried lot of samples with updated methods but its not working for hostnameverfier.

so i checked few articles to create sslbundles.I was able to create sslbundle with spring.ssl properties with classpath resources.

But my requirement is i have to take the the .p12/.key and .crt from another repo .which we have configure with config -server-->config-server-repo-->poject/profile-->.jks/.key/.crt files
which works by cloud:// path
spring.ssl.bundle.jks.server.keystore.location=classpath:test.p12 -->works but i want

spring.ssl.bundle.jks.server.keystore.location=cloud://test.p12-->not work
also for
pring.ssl.bundle.pem.client.keystore.certificate=cloud://client.crt
spring.ssl.bundle.pem.client.keystore.private-key=cloud://client.key

i tried lot of combinations with forward and backward slash with file: as well but it dose not get correct file path.

can some one help how i can pass these properties to spring.ssl or through java class i can set it.

Thanks,
Shalaka.

I tried some classic code with latest methods for ssl and sslbundle